# Set the fill color of a shape

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to set the fill colour of a shape using HEX so I have

```
selCellColour=ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

To get the colour of the cell and want to use

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor = Hex(selCellColour)
```

But I keep getting the a Type Mismatch error message. How can I resolve this, I don't want to colour to RGB I want to use the HEX value.

Comment: It looks like you can't set the forecolor to a hex value. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorformat

Comment: It's by design that the forecolor accepts RGB(red-green-blue) value only. You can try to transfer the HEX values to the RGB values. Take the thread [Fill a cell with color based on it's HEX value in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743199/fill-a-cell-with-color-based-on-its-hex-value-in-excel-2013) for example.

Comment: @Owen OK thanks, if you post answers I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ForeColor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.fillformat.forecolor) property of a Shape's Fill is of type [ColorFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorformat). ColorFormat can only be assigned an RGB or a [color](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorformat.schemecolor) in the color scheme.

Per the ColorFormat page:

> You can set colors to an explicit red-green-blue value (by using the
>   RGB property) or to a color in the color scheme (by using the
>   SchemeColor property).

So, if you don't prefer RGB, you could explore the color scheme method.